# Loading global data for server using Flask and gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I have implemented simple API using the Flask framework and now I am trying to deploy it to gunicorn server.

My server script looks as follows:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

class Server(object):
   def __init__(self, data):
       self.data = data

@app.route("/api_method", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def api_method():
     return server.data

if __name__ == '__main__':
     with smart_open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
         server = Server(f.read())
     app.run()
```

When I run this from console as "Flask app" than everything is ok, but when I try to run this under gunicorn then it does not see the server. I was able to fixe it only by moving server creation up, but I had to hardcode the path.

Is there some way how to load something like my Server class at the startup of the gunicorn server and then read it within API methods?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are my recommendations on how to do this.

**1.** I wouldn't rely on the global `server` variable if it needs to be instantiated this way. Since it's instantiated after the app's creation it would be better to pass it explicitly into the application somehow. This way you can access it from other modules ([blueprints](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/blueprints/), [pluggable views](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/views/), etc.) For example, you can use Flask's configuration mechanism:

```
app.config['server'] = Server(f.read())

#...then in your view functions...

return app.config['server'].data
```

Or through flask's [globals object](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#application-globals), `g`:

```
@app.before_request
def add_server_to_globals():
    with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
        g.server = Server(f.read())

#...then in your view functions...
return g.server.data
```

Or by subclassing `Flask` and passing it in through the initializer.

**2.** Now that you're using gunicorn, you cannot rely on the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block, as this is only executed when you run the file, not when it's imported. Gunicorn works by importing the application object (see [how APP_MODULE is explained in the docs](http://gunicorn-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/run.html#gunicorn)) and handing it off to gunicorn's WSGI server, so your code for instantiating `Server` will not run.

The other new requirement from unicorn is that you cannot rely on `sys.argv`, since this will be gunicorn's `sys.argv`, which is different from whatever argument you are currently passing in when running the file directly.

To replace the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block you can use `before_request` as I did above to run some code before the application handles its first request. I recommend using an environment variable or a [config file](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/config/#configuring-from-files) to pass in your argument to the `Server` class. For example:

```
@app.before_request
def add_server_to_globals():
    with open(os.environ['SERVER_FILE']) as f:
        g.server = Server(f.read())
```

Then run your application with the environment variable set:

```
$ SERVER_FILE=blah.txt gunicorn app:app
[2015-02-24 10:10:20 -0800] [3217] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.2.1
...
```

**3.** You can also take a look at the ["application factory"](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/appfactories/) pattern described in the flask docs to replace the `if __name__ == '__main__'` block. But in this case it's not quite necessary. The use for an application factory would be if you want to instantiate the `Server` object only once (for performance reasons).

[Here's some fully working code based on your example](https://gist.github.com/lost-theory/d6beaeb7ae5ead166227#file-app_simple-py).

[Here's another example using an application factory](https://gist.github.com/lost-theory/d6beaeb7ae5ead166227#file-app_simple-py).

Comment: Actually the version with global object g does work only for one request. I've realised that then loaded object disappear which not what I actually want. So app.config['server'] = ... is the correct solution.

Comment: Ah that's right. Sorry about that. I was mistaken about `before_first_request` vs. `before_request`. I've updated my post with the correct information and added an example on how to use before_request with an application factory.

Comment: Thank you, in my case the file can be quiet big and can be remote on S3 (the reason why I'm using `smart_open` library instead of standard `open`). So still loading the file before every request would be quiet a problem, but the `app.config['server'] = Server(f.read())` works well for me.

Answer (score 2):

Simply :)

```
with smart_open(sys.argv[2]) as f:
    server = Server(f.read())
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Logic is already give you by Steven Kryskalla in his answer.

**But ensure that you keep `app.run()` inside `if __name__=="__main__"` since you do not want that to be run when gunicorn imports server**

**EDIT:
There has to be actually sys.argv[2] instead, because in the sys.argv[1] is the path to the server app.**

Comment: I've actually tried this and you're basically right, but there is one peculiarity. 

It actually changes to sys.argv[2], because running the server the second argument is path to the server script. 

So there might be problem when I would like to have the same code to run on both native Flask server and the gunicorn server.

Comment: yeah you are right. I just tried to convey simple fix without rechecking what command should be used. :)